# How to toggle value of list element on click

Tags: jquery

Given a list of items with a + sign attached to show more, how I can toggle the list element with the `+` to a `-` on click and back to `+` when clicking again?

```
<ul class="practice-areas-list">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>



$('ul.practice-areas-list').each(function() {
  $('li:gt(4)', this).hide();
});
$('ul.practice-areas-list').each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('li').length > 4) {
    $(this).append('<li>+</li>').find('li:last').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings(':gt(4)').toggle();
    });
  }
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/8jLg7bu1/1/)**

Comment: Take a look at w3schools accordions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one line to do this:

```
  $(this).html( $(this).html() == '+' ? '-':'+' )
```

```js
$('ul.practice-areas-list').each(function() {
  $('li:gt(4)', this).hide();
  if ($(this).find('li').length > 4) {
    $(this).append('<li>+</li>').find('li:last').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings(':gt(4)').toggle();
      $(this).html( $(this).html() == '+' ? '-':'+' )
    });
  }
});
```

```css
li{
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="practice-areas-list">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The inside of that line, `$(this).html() == '+' ? '-':'+'` says if the content of that list item appended at the end is a plus sign, change it to a  minus sign, else change it to a plus sign. It then takes that content and assigns it as the html for that last list item. Note that I also combined your two `.each` loops.

Comment: That's the ternary operator I was trying to think of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed some of your code to increase readability, but I think it was for the best.  So, basically, check for `.is(":visible")` and if it's true set it to -, if not then +.

```js
$hideArea = $('ul.practice-areas-list li:not(.expand):gt(4)').hide();

$expand = $(".expand").click(function() {
  $hideArea.toggle();
  if ($hideArea.is(":visible")) {
    $expand.html("-");
  } else {
    $expand.html("+");
  }
});
```

```css
li{
  list-style-type:none;
}
.expand {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="practice-areas-list">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="expand">+</li>
</ul>
```